# Why does the P-V graph for a cyclic process make a loop?

Tags: thermodynamics

Assuming the same path is not followed when the gas performs expansion and compression irreversibly in a cyclic process, why is a loop formed on the P-V graph?

Isn't a rectangular hyperbola made when we plot a graph for an inverse ratio?

If considered individually (that is possible, right?), wouldn't it look something like this:
[image]

[image]
is this 'loop' correct too?

Am I correct in my approach or am I missing out on something important here?

Comment: @Poutnik https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RectangularHyperbola.html

Comment: See the answer update. I have also deleted my obsolete comments.

Comment: @Mel  I know the last graph is drawn for illustrative purposes, but the "orange" curve doesn't satisfy the requirements of a mathematical function. Therefore, I don't know if that is possible to achieve...

Comment: @MetalStorm Is that the reason the apparently 'correct' one (the one which we've been taught) is inverted to form the loop the other way?

Comment: @Mel If by the correct one you refer to the one we can see in the second image, then yes. The lower curve that returns to the starting point at least mathematically makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A hyperbolic process state path happens for isothermal processes.

The other curve describes very peculiar process, when the gas is during expansion being heated up by a specific way and than being cooled down to the initial temperature.

If endpoints of both paths have the same temperature and pressure, it leads inevitably to a closed cyclic path.

---

A pure rectangular hyperbole means an isothermal process (for ideal gases).

If there is a deviation from a hyperbole toward the origin, the gas is temporarily cooled down on the process path. Or the amount of gas has temporarily decreased, like in temporarily open systems in the [Otto cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otto_cycle) for gasoline combustion engines.

If there is a deviation from a hyperbole away of the origin, the gas is temporarily warmed up on the process path. Or the amount of gas has temporarily increased.

The individual expansion part shape suggests the gas temporarily obtain absolute temperature about twice as high, compared to the endpoint values.

Comment: I added another image, could you confirm if it's correct?

Comment: I assume it is. I have not been used to the "rectangular hyperbola" term, but it was after while clear what it means.

Comment: Ah, I see. It does make sense now. Can't upvote this (I don't have the reputation), but thanks! As for the figure though, another user pointed out it's not mathematically correct, which probably is the case, or else it would have been there on my textbook.

Comment: @Mel You can still click the "tick" sign on the left to accept the answer. This should be below the arrow that is pointing down.